# How do convert row result to like array($result)

Tags: php, arrays

How do add my row result to to array like array($output_variable); i have tried:

```
<?php
    require('init.php');
    session_start();
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT item_name , quantity FROM books WHERE book = 1644445');
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $da  = $row['item_name'];  
        $qty  = $row['quantity'];  
        $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM promo WHERE code='$da' LIMIT 1");
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
            $id = $row['id'];
            $type = $row['name'];
            $code = $row['recharge'];
            if(preg_match('/(9mobile)/i', $type))
                $type   = '5';
            if(preg_match('/(Glo)/i', $type))
                $type   = '5';
            if(preg_match('/(MTN)/i', $type))
                $type   = '5';
            if(preg_match('/(AIRTEL)/i', $type))
                $type   = '5';
            $disp = str_split($code, $type);
            $num = $qty;
            for($b = 0; $b<$num; $b++){
                $shown .= $disp[$b]; 
            }
            for($c = $num; $c<sizeof($disp); $c++){
                $dreturn .= $disp[$c]; #dreturn
            }
            $pa = array('$disp[$b]');
            $pa = implode(' ' ,$pa);
            echo "<br/>$pa";
            mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE IGNORE promo SET recharge='12345678910' WHERE id=$id");
        }
    }
?>
```

all i get as output is $disp[$b]
 i appliciate your time in my soluction

Comment: I don't understand. You're talking about this line ? $pa = array('$disp[$b]');

Comment: Yes, he is. See my answer.

Comment: Then he should reformulate his question, like: My variable `$pa` only contains the string `$disp[$b]` but not the content of that `$disp[$b]`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) First thing, by using `'` you tell PHP not to parse the string for any variables but to show it "as-is" (`$` as dollar character, not variable beginning). By removing the `'` from it, you have the value of `$disp[$b]` copied to `$pa`.

Example 1 (proposed fix):

```
$pa = array($disp[$b]);
```

Example 2:

```
<?php
$foo = 'bar!';
echo '$foo';
?>
```

If you execute example 2, you see `$foo` as output, no `bar!`. Just replace single quote in line `3` with double quote and you see `bar!`. Like: `echo "$foo";`

You even have the same result by using curly braces: `echo '{$foo}';` versus `echo "{$foo}";`.

**PHP version:** `PHP 7.1.11 (cli) (built: Oct 25 2017 20:54:15) ( NTS MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015) x64 )`

**Getting off-topic, but still worth to improve:**

2) Then you double-use `$row` (see both `while()` declarations). You should rename these both into separate variables. You may want to name your first `$row` as `$book` and second as `$promo` to clarify your code and not loose any data that you may later depend on.

3) Then there is no need to copy array elements to (local) variables (since PHP4 as I remember correctly). You can directly use the array elements, after you have fixed 1) and 2). Means, do something like `$disp = str_split($promo['recharge'], $type);`. It also looks like that the whole code is really messy, asking for further problems. I would recommend using `error_reporting(-1);` to be sure that all future warnings are enabled, [see docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php). This however should only be enabled for debugging, of course.

Comment: statements are not a solution. Add some code along with some description like what is changed.BTW not a down-voter

Comment: I just want to put query array

Comment: And once more, for 1) I have rewritten it.

Comment: Added more examples with repeatable results (tested it with mentioned version of PHP).

Comment: With your method i get every data on query multiple times example i have 5 id in query echo id becomes 3333311111555557777799999 how we i resolve this

Comment: So you need them unique? Then [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) is maybe what you want.

Comment: No, your code needs more rewrite and I won't recommend SQL `DISTINCT` as this comes with a performance penalty.